# how to compare two arrays for similarity

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison

I've struggled with tweaking this code in comparing two arrays in C++. I've seen other examples done here on this site and adjusted my code accordingly from advice. But when I run this code with the same elements and different elements and also different size arrays. It always says its true and the arrays are equal. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to make appropriate corrections? thanks

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int arr1[6] ={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int arr2[6] ={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int *p1 = arr1;
int *p2 = arr2;
bool equal = true;
int index = 0;

 while(index < 6){
        if(p1[index] == p2[index]){
            equal = true;
            index ++;
        }

        else
        {
            equal = false;  
            break;
        }
 }

 if(equal == true)
     cout<<" The arrays are equal"<< endl;
 else 
     cout<<" The arrays are equal"<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

code here

Comment: Can you give an example, which calculates true but you expect false?

Comment: You were printing `"the arrays are equal"` on both branches of the `if`-`else` statement. See [this working demo](http://ideone.com/oobfyw) and think about using `std::equal` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this you problem is that both your outputs say the same thing.

Modify the last if acordingly:

```
 if(equal == true)

     cout<<" The arrays are equal"<< endl;

  else 

     cout<<" The arrays are not equal"<< endl;
```

Comment: Unfortunately OP edited the question to fix the problem. But from me +1 anyway.

Comment: Apologies, a friend of mine pointed out what I was dong wrong. I corrected the error . Thanks. I have another question that I will post up in a minute.